# digital tablet which is capable of giving input to my applet?

Tags: tablet, applet, input-devices

I have java project , which is currently developing and will be deployed in ubuntu only. Here i need a digital tablet which is having both mouse and pen, which is capable of giving input to my applet in my project.

Most of digital tablets only supports for windows and apple OSes. can there is any digital tablet to meet my above requirements??

tanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Many digital tablets are supported in Ubuntu, including many models from [Wacom](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wacom), as well as some less well known manufacturers such as [Huion, KYE, UC-Logic, Waltop through the DIGImend project](https://digimend.github.io/tablets/). All of these tablets will be able to interact with your applet. *However*, if you need to measure how hard the pen is being pressed (pressure), that is a Java question, which is best suited for StackOverflow.